# Pandas: Concatenate two dataframes with different column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames

```
df1 = 
    actorID         actorName
0   annie_potts     Annie Potts
1   bill_farmer     Bill Farmer
2   don_rickles     Don Rickles
3   erik_von_detten Erik von Detten
4   greg-berg       Greg Berg

df2 = 
    directorID      directorName
0   john_lasseter   John Lasseter
1   joe_johnston    Joe Johnston
2   donald_petrie   Donald Petrie
3   forest_whitaker Forest Whitaker
4   charles_shyer   Charles Shyer
```

What I ideally want is a concatenation of these two dataframes, like `pd.concat((df1, df2))`:

```
    actorID-directorID   actorName-directorName
0   annie_potts          Annie Potts
1   bill_farmer          Bill Farmer
2   don_rickles          Don Rickles
3   erik_von_detten      Erik von Detten
4   greg-berg            Greg Berg
5   john_lasseter        John Lasseter
6   joe_johnston         Joe Johnston
7   donald_petrie        Donald Petrie
8   forest_whitaker      Forest Whitaker
9   charles_shyer        Charles Shyer
```

however I want there to be an easy way to specify that I want to join `df1.actorName` and `df2.directorName` together, and `actorID / directorID`. How can I do this?

Comment: Try `df1.append(df2)`

Comment: That doesn't work. That creates two more columns instead of merging the columns together.

Comment: Sorry, ya that won't work if the column names are different.  Here is a way to do it, I'm sure there is a better way so i'll just leave this a comment.  `pd.DataFrame(np.r_[df1.values, df2.values], columns=['actorID-directorID', 'actorName-directorName'])`

Comment: Rename column headers in both data frame and use `append` or `concat`   :)

Comment: @GoBrewers14: I went with a similar solution to that. But like you mentioned, it's not very ideal.